# ASAR Limitations on Node API: spawn a child process

Tags: node.js, electron, asar

I’m currently developing an electron app that has, at some point, to convert an HTML file into a PDF file. For this purpose, I use the native node module `html-pdf` which is based on `phantomjs`.

It works well when the application is not packed but when it is under *asar*, there is an *uncaught exception* because `html-pdf` cannot spawn a child process.

**The stack error**

```
internal/child_process.js:302 Uncaught Error: spawn ENOTDIR

exports._errnoException @ util.js:890
ChildProcess.spawn @ internal/child_process.js:302
exports.spawn @ child_process.js:379
PdfExec @ /Users/graphfx/html2pdf/html2pdf.asar/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/…:87
PdfToFile @ /Users/graphfx/html2pdf/html2pdf.asar/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/…:83
convert @ index.html:35
onclick @ index.html:19
```

I suppose that is due to the *asar* [Limitations on Node API](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.27.0/tutorial/application-packaging/#limitations-on-node-api) but I really need to pack my app in *asar* due to the *260 character path length limit* on Windows.

I have also tried using the option  `--unpack-dir 'node_modules'` when building the *asar* package but the problem persists.

**Reproduce the error**

```
git clone https://github.com/Graphfx/html2pdf
cd html2pdf
npm install
npm run asar-pack
npm run start-asar
```

---

Does someone know how solve this problem?

Comment: It's not possible to do that with asar, thus the solution was to use npm 3.x.x that prevents the 260 character path issue.